# Unable to use NDde.dll in windows service

Tags: c#, windows

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NDde.Client;
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timeDelay;
        int count;  
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timeDelay = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timeDelay.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(WorkProcess);  
        }

      public void WorkProcess(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)  
        {  
            string process = "Timer Tick " + count;  
            LogService(process);  
            count++;  
        }  
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)  
        {  
            LogService("Service is Started");  
            timeDelay.Enabled = true;  
        }  
        protected override void OnStop()  
        {  
            LogService("Service Stoped");  
            timeDelay.Enabled = false;  
        }  
        private void LogService(string content)  
        {

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\TestServiceLog.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);  
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);  
            sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);  
            sw.WriteLine(content+this.GetFirefoxUrl());  
            sw.Flush();  
            sw.Close();  
        }  

        public string GetFirefoxUrl()
        {
            DdeClient dde = new DdeClient("Firefox", "WWW_GetWindowInfo");
            dde.Connect();
            string url = dde.Request("URL", int.MaxValue);
            dde.Disconnect();
            return url;
        }
    }
}
```

Hi, I have written the above code but I am unable to perform the task GetFirefoxUrl(). Its giving me the following error. How can I resolve this?

> Service cannot be started. NDde.DdeException: The client failed to connect to "Firefox|WWW_GetWindowInfo".  Make sure the server application is running and that it supports the specified service name and topic name pair. ---> NDde.Foundation.DdemlException: The client failed to connect to "Firefox|WWW_GetWindowInfo".  Make sure the server application is running and that it supports the specified service name and topic name pair.
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
>          at NDde.Advanced.DdeContext.DdeThread.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
>          at NDde.Client.DdeClient.Connect()
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at NDde.Client.DdeClient.Connect()
>          at Test.Service1.GetFirefoxUrl()
>          at Test.Service1.LogService(String content)
>          at Test.Service1.OnStart(String[] args)
>          at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)

I have checked the other threads related to this none of them gave me a solution. I hope some one guide me to achieve this.

Comment: Can you describe what this code is expected to do?

Comment: At a quick glance, it looks like you are trying to access FireFox from a Windows Service. This is very, very difficult because Windows Services don't run as the same user running FireFox, and runs in "session 0", which is a different session than the one user apps run in.

Comment: Actuall this code keep checking for the firefox browser and detect the url of the firefox addressbar.

Comment: @vcsjones Is there any other way to achieve this. I need to perform the task continuously.

Comment: Don't use a service but a regular executable that runs through one of the many ways something can be started automatically (like through HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run). Alternatively, if you need to centralize handling across users, have the service listen for logon events and spawn a process in the session, communicating with it through IPC. The latter is fairly complicated, however.

Comment: DDE is a very old and mostly obsolete technology that really shouldn't be used in new software anymore. UI Automation is more suited for this task ([for example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26348382/)). Depending on what you're *actually* trying to do, a Firefox extension or an external (intercepting) proxy may be more appropriate. The latter can intercept all HTTP traffic, regardless of browser used (it's the kind of thing you'd use on a corporate network).