# Get Firefox URL using windows services?

Tags: c#, windows-services

This is my code which i used to get Firefox current URL.

```
 try
        {
DdeClient dde = new DdeClient("firefox", "WWW_GetWindowInfo");
dde.Connect();
string url = dde.Request("URL", int.MaxValue);
string[] text = url.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, 
StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
dde.Disconnect();
Debug.WriteLine(text[0].Substring(1));
return text[0].Substring(1);
catch
        {
            return null;
        }
```

When i debug windows services without installing this code give me a correct URL and work fine for me but when i install  Windows services then this code return only null value.
Any idea what the problem is? i want to monitor the firefox activity using windows services.

Comment: try run service with an administrator user

Comment: A Windows Service is isolated from all the other users currently logged on and so cannot interact with them, this is even more true for DDE which uses windows messages.  You either need to communicate with a custom client running in each session or rethink your approach, the latter seems best as what your doing seems quite brittle anyway.

Comment: In my program i get google chrome ,Firefox and Internet Explorer current url using windows services. My windows services is successfully installed and running and get current url of internet explore successfully but return null when get google chrome and Firefox  URL. And the same code i run in console application which work perfectly.

Comment: Any other way to monitor Browser without using Windows services?

Comment: An HTTP Proxy server would intercept all HTTP traffic from Browsers (and others)

Comment: i think i find my answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521263/unable-to-use-ndde-dll-in-windows-service).